# Unhandled exception on exit

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I'm trying to evaluate whether [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) would work for us, in a XAML/WPF application.

Currently, we're working with MS's WebBrowser, which has severe limitations.

What we have, in our app, is a window which displays one of several custom controls, one of which contains a browser control that loads a web page containing a map.

For testing, I've created a custom control that contains a WebBrowser hard-coded to http://www.google.com.

I then created a second custom control that contains a ChromiumWebBrowser hard-coded to http://www.google.com.

I'm doing nothing with either browser control in code, I'm simply making the user controls that wrap them visible or collapsed.

But if I have the ChromiumWebBrowser included in the XAML, whether I make it visible or not, on exit I get an exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll
Additional information: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
```

Just to make it clear, if my custom control contains this, I do not get an exception:

```
<KtWpf:KorUserControl 
        x:Class="KtWpf.CEFSharpUtilityMap"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:KtWpf="clr-namespace:KtWpf" mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
        >
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top">CEFSharp</TextBox>
        <WebBrowser
                x:Name="mapBrowser"
                Source="http://www.google.com"
                />
    </DockPanel>
</KtWpf:KorUserControl>
```

If it contains this, I do:

```
<KtWpf:KorUserControl 
        x:Class="KtWpf.CEFSharpUtilityMap"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:cefSharp="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"
        xmlns:KtWpf="clr-namespace:KtWpf" mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
        >
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top">CEFSharp</TextBox>
        <cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser 
                x:Name="mapBrowser" 
                Address="http://www.google.com"
            />
    </DockPanel>
</KtWpf:KorUserControl>
```

Any ideas?

I'm using CefSharp.Wfp version 49.0.0, from NuGet. (And CefSharp.Common and cef.redist.x64, though I get the same thing building for x86.)

=== Adding callstack ===

```
>   WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()  Unknown
PresentationCore.dll!MS.Internal.Media.VisualTreeUtils.AsVisual(System.Windows.DependencyObject element, out System.Windows.Media.Visual visual, out System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Visual3D visual3D)    Unknown
PresentationCore.dll!MS.Internal.Media.VisualTreeUtils.AsNonNullVisual(System.Windows.DependencyObject element, out System.Windows.Media.Visual visual, out System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Visual3D visual3D) Unknown
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(System.Windows.DependencyObject reference) Unknown
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Visual.ClearTreeBits(System.Windows.DependencyObject e, System.Windows.Media.VisualFlags treeFlag, System.Windows.Media.VisualFlags nodeFlag) Unknown
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Visual.VisualAncestorChanged.remove(System.Windows.Media.Visual.AncestorChangedEventHandler value)    Unknown
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.PresentationSource.RemoveSourceChangedHandler(System.Windows.IInputElement e, System.Windows.SourceChangedEventHandler handler) Unknown
CefSharp.Wpf.dll!CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser.Dispose(bool isdisposing)  Unknown
CefSharp.Wpf.dll!CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser.Dispose()  Unknown
CefSharp.Core.dll!CefSharp.Cef.Shutdown()   Unknown
CefSharp.Core.dll!CefSharp.Cef.ParentProcessExitHandler(object sender, System.EventArgs e)  Unknown
```

Comment: Do you have a full stack trace?

Comment: Is there a reason you asked this again here?

Comment: I originally posted this question in the CEFSharp Google Group, and got no response. Reading through the other questions, I was directed to gitter, and repeated it there. I found gitter impossible to read. Given it's chat format, I couldn't even tell if anyone had responded to me. So I reposted the question here, where any answers provided would not be lost to posterity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we need to do is to take control of the initialization and shutdown.

In App.OnStartup():

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    Cef.Initialize();
    ...
}
```

in App.OnExit():

```
protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
{
    Cef.Shutdown();
    base.OnExit(e);
}
```